# Defining an Ember computed property based on an array of properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to define a computed property that depends upon a set of properties, which are specified as an array. The example is given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hT8aJ/1/):

```
var MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    properties: ['red', 'blue'],

    red: 'i am red',
    blue: 'blue am i',

    defineMagic: function () {
        var thiz = this;

        Ember.defineProperty(thiz, 'magic', Ember.computed(function () {
           console.log('i am called');
            return thiz.getProperties(thiz.get('properties'));
       }).property(thiz.get('properties').toString()/*what goes here */));
   }
});
```

So far, I have used Ember's defineProperty method to define a computed property. But the computed property does not get recomputed if the underlying properties change, as noted in the comments in the fiddle. Be sure to activate console, as I am trying to validate against the console output.

Is this possible at all in Ember, and if so; how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the magic of `Function#apply`. `apply` calls a function by translating the passed array into an arguments list. (`Function#call`, on the other hand, takes a normal comma separated list of arguments). Try this:

```
var func = function () { return this.get('properties'); };
var args = this.get('properties').concat([func]);

Ember.defineProperty(this, 'magic', Ember.computed.apply(this, args));
```

This is equivalent to

```
Ember.defineProperty(this, 'magic', Ember.computed('red', 'blue', func));
```

Also: in a computed property `this` refers to the object of which it is a property, so you don't want to be referencing `that`/`thiz` etc to get to the object.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the `Function#apply`!. But the code `Ember.computed('red', 'blue', func)` is not correct, as the [doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_computed) needs an argument as a function. I have built upon your suggestion and updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hT8aJ/2/), and it works as I expect it to. And, yes, agree on the `thiz` usage; but it's still not corrected on the latest fiddle

Comment: Regardless of what the doc says, the `Ember.computed` usage is correct. Only the last argument need be a function, it is preceded by the dependent keys.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle with my recommended code:http://jsfiddle.net/hT8aJ/4/ and it seems to work as expected. One other thing to remember as you work on this, which I don't think is coming into play here, is that computed functions aren't computed until you `get` them, so you have to be careful not to be confused by `console.log`s inside the computed function firing or not firing.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up; marked your response as the correct answer!

Comment: Again, the `get` requirement on the computed properties goofed me up a bit when I integrated these changes into my code; then looked up the tests for the `Ember.observes()`. Think Ember does this internally when a property is bound to the views?